# undefined is not an object(evaluating 'Object.keys(inboundState)')

Tags: javascript, react-native

This error only occurs after clearing all cache. The app is developed using javascript and react-native. We are using Expo with an iOS simulator, a real iPhone and an Android tablet. When the app reloads the program starts without a hitch.

This is the error from iOS

```
undefined is not an object(evaluating 'Object.keys(inboundState)')
```

Additional info listed with the message as follows

```
defaultStateReconciller
autoRehydrate.js:66:14

dispatch
createStore.js:178:36
```

This is how it manifest on Android
Requested keys of a value that is not an object.

Additional info listed with the message as follows

```
defaultStateReconciller

dispatch
createStore.js:190:3
```

The yarn.lock has these lines
"@redux-offline/redux-offline@^2.3.2":
  version "2.3.2"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@redux-offline/redux-offline/-/redux-offline-2.3.2.tgz#ecdb324e198bd4aa6b965f651ec589f66c8f2605"
  dependencies:
    babel-runtime "^6.26.0"
    redux-persist "^4.5.0"

redux-persist@^4.5.0:
  version "4.10.2"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/redux-persist/-/redux-persist-4.10.2.tgz#8efdb16cfe882c521a78a6d0bfdfef2437f49f96"
  dependencies:
    json-stringify-safe "^5.0.1"
    lodash "^4.17.4"
    lodash-es "^4.17.4"

redux-persist@^5.9.1:
  version "5.9.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/redux-persist/-/redux-persist-5.9.1.tgz#83bd4abd526ef768f63fceee338fa9d8ed6552d6"

App.js

```js
import { createStore, combineReducers, compose } from 'redux'
import { offline } from '@redux-offline/redux-offline'
import offlineConfig from '@redux-offline/redux-offline/lib/defaults'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, appReducer)

offlineConfig.effect = (effect, action) => {
  return fetchApi(effect.endpoint, effect.payload ? effect.payload : null,
    effect.method ? effect.method : null, effect.headers ? effect.headers : null)
}

export const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  [],
  compose( 
    offline(offlineConfig)
  )
)
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <Initialize />
          <Root>
            <RootStack />
          </Root>
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    )
```

Comment: "This error only occurs after clearing all cache"... Ok, so you are trying to use something before it is loaded. Before the cache was cleared it was read from cache (fast), but after you cleared the cache it needs to get it from the network, and therefore isn't ready to be used when you are using it.

Comment: Sounds like you are using `redux-persist`, can share configuration related `redux-persist`?

Comment: redux-persist is being used. I have included references to redux-persist from the yarn.lock as well as configuration from App.js
thanks

Comment: Any solutions? I'm facing same problems

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue posted on gihub regarding this
https://github.com/redux-offline/redux-offline/issues/362#issuecomment-552190934

Try this workaround,

```
//redux-offline/node_modules/lib/autRehydrate.js:62
function defaultStateReconciler(state, inboundState, reducedState, log) {
  var newState = _extends({}, reducedState);
  if (typeof inboundState !== 'object') return newState;  // add this line.
  //...rest 
}
```